# How do you write if else statements within a Shellscript for Mac OS?

Tags: bash, macos

My goal is a simple one. I am trying to write a MacOs Shell Script containing if else statements. Specifically, I want the script to create a new file called "targets" if a file named "newFolder" exists on my desktop. Secondly I want the script to create a new folder called "days" if a folder named "ifolder" exists on the desktop and if it does not exist create a folder called "reactProjects".

Here is what I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ..
cd ..
cd desktop

if exist newFolder mkdir targets

if exist targets mkdir days else mkdir reactProjects
```

But I am having an error occur when I try run it through the terminal. The error states:

```
ifExample.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

This is my first script shell, so I may have some syntax mistakes, but please let me know if you understand how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: You are writing a `bash` script; that's nothing to do with the operating system on which you are writing `bash`. (Though in this case, macOS provides a fairly strong implication as to which *version* of `bash` you are using.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know more about conditionals in bash so I encourage you to read [this article](https://linuxhint.com/bash_conditional_statement/).

But before that your solution should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ..
cd ..
cd desktop

if [ -f newFolder ]; then
   mkdir targets
fi

if [ -d ifolder ]; then
   mkdir days
else
   mkdir reactProjects
fi
```

Comment: Thanks so much your answer and this link! I'll be sure to read it.